# Using text-overflow with element floated beside it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

I have three problems.

1. The width for the left hand element needs to be defined such that the `text-overflow: ellipsis` will have effect
2. The controls that are floated to the right are always visible on the line and not pushed down by the left hand element
3. The container for this group of HTML is re-sizable so the size of article-title cannot be fixed. The controls will always be ~160px though.

The container for this group of HTML is re-sizable. Dragging the result pane of [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TPdch/) is exactly how it works in my current app.

The CSS

```
.article-title {
    float: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 85%;
}
.pull-right {
    float: right;
}
.browse-issue {
    margin-right: 1ex;
}
```

The HTML

```
<span class="article-title" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris a.">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris a.</span>
<div class="pull-right">
    <button type="button" class="browse-issue btn" style="">Browse Issue</button>
    <button type="button" class="print btn"><i class="icon-print"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with your point # 1

Comment: Can the order of the elements be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a tentative solution that involves wrapping you snippet in a `div`:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="article-title" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</span>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="browse-issue btn" style="">Browse Issue</button>
        <button type="button" class="print btn"><i class="icon-print"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

which can be styled as follows:

```
.wrapper {
    outline: 1px dotted red;
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 0px;
}
.article-title {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 170px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight: bold;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}
.pull-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    outline: 1px dotted blue;
}
.browse-issue {
    margin-right: 1ex;
}
```

You can ignore the `outline` styling, I put those in to help me see the element boxes.

The trick is to define a `wrapper` block element and use `absolute` positioning to place the `pull-right` div to the right and top of the wrapper.

You then `display: block` the `article-title` element and allow a `right-margin` value sufficient to prevent the test from flowing under the buttons.

The `text-overflow: ellipsis` was working but since the text was not long enough, you were not seeing the effect.

I also adjusted the `line-height`, but that is optional.

This should be pretty close to what you need.

Fiddle Reference: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/PmUje/